# Nicotine withdrawal’s effect on sleep rhythms?

Tags: nicotine, drug-withdrawal

Can nicotine withdrawal  cause oversleeping? My understanding that nicotine decreases sleep duration.

Answer (score 3):

[Nicotine withdrawal](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4542051/) can cause insomnia rather then oversleeping.

> The Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM-5) reports 7 primary symptoms associated with nicotine withdrawal: irritability/anger/frustration, anxiety, depressed mood, difficulty concentrating, increased appetite, insomnia, and restlessness